# Get number of files from zip file header before fully uploaded

Tags: php, linux, debian

In php (running in Debian) is it possible to get the number of files inside a zip archive by reading zip file header while the zip file is still being uploaded?

Or are there any linux commands I can run inside php to get the information?

Basically I need to know the number of files inside the zip files before users have finished uploading their zip files so that I know what to expect in advance.

( Is there a chance that file header is not the first chunk of data to be uploaded in any file? )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the zip file without actually unzipping the file by running

```
unzip -l <filename.zip>
```

But, `unzip` has to be installed in your system

Comment: thanks, will this work while the file is being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like it's gonna be hard doing it at download/upload time...  As the info and diagram [**in this page**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8688/Extracting-files-from-a-remote-ZIP-archive), the files are grouped one after the other, and at the end of the file there is kind of a summary with all the files information.  So, there's no way to know how many files you have in there until you reach the *Central Directory* chunk of data.

[image]

If you can test from time to time while uploading big ZIP files, maybe you can use Linux/Unix's `strings` and check how many strings are there with `UT` at the end of their names.

```
$ strings -at d file.zip
     30 lettersUT
     65 abcde
    101 barUT
    132 Y Y Z
    184 lettersUT
    261 barUT
```

In the above example, there are 2 files: `letters` and `bar`.  The names are being repeated at the end, as part of the Central Directory.

Comment: thanks very much for the info. looks like it is not possible after all